NextJS 14 redirect from server file
I have a NextJS 14 app that uses an agent.ts file for defining and handling API interactions with Axios. In this, I want to handle 401, 403, 404 and 500 status codes in a common way across my application; for example, redirecting to the login page.
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  async (response) => {
    await sleep(2000);
    return response;
  },
  (error: AxiosError) => {
    const {
      data,
      status,
      config,
    }: { data: any; status: number; config: AxiosRequestConfig } =
      error.response as AxiosResponse;
    switch (status) {
      case 401:
        // Redirect to error page
      case: 403:
        toast.error("You are not allowed to perform this action");
        break
      case 404:
        // Redirect to not found page
        break;
      case 500:
      // Redirect to server error page
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);


I can't use the useRouter() hook because this is not a client-side component but consumed by one. I have tried using redirect("/") but this throws an error and does not redirect.
****.ts:47 Uncaught (in promise) Error: NEXT_REDIRECT
    at getRedirectError (redirect.js:49:19)
    at redirect (redirect.js:60:11)
    at eval (agent.ts:69:13)
    at async Axios.request (Axios.js:36:20)
    at async EventStore.loadRaceEvents (raceEventStore.ts:35:24)
    at Axios.request (Axios.js:40:49)
    at async ***.***(***.ts:35:24)

What are my options to achieve this?
Sample call:
  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadUsers() {
      setLoading(true);
      await agent.Users.list().then((response) => {
        setUsers(response);
        setLoading(false);
      });
    }

    loadUsers();
  }, []);

Thanks
